# Sort a list of strings with a given order in python

Tags: python, list

I need to sort a list of strings that looks like this:

```
["green", "red", "yellow", "blue"]
```

And I have a list that contains a lot of words in the order they should be sorted:

```
["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "teal", "blue", "purple"]
```

If it's helpful, I can also write the list that stipulates the correct order into a dictionary, like this:

```
{"red" : 0, "orange" : 1, "yellow" : 2, "green" : 3, "teal" : 4, "blue": 5, "purple" : 6}
```

The final goal is to sort the list of strings into the correct order, like this:

```
["red", "yellow", "green", "blue"]
```

But I don't know how I can use this order to sort my list. Is it possible to do it with sorted() or lst.sort()? I have looked into the key parameter of these two functions but don't know how to use it in this situation.

Comment: Look into the key= parameter of the sorted function

Comment: I tried using numpy methods and retrieve the word-order pair from the dictionary using dict.items()..

Comment: SO = Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: I came to SO having read the documents on docs.python.org and several other pages discussing sorted and the list.sort method. Maybe I have asked this in the wrong way or haven't found the correct document that people are referring to, doesn't mean I'm trying to get someone to do homework problems for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
sortorder = {"red" : 0, "orange" : 1, "yellow" : 2, "green" : 3, "teal" : 4, "blue": 5, "purple" : 6}
to_sort = ["green", "red", "yellow", "blue"]

sorted_list = sorted(to_sort, key=lambda col:sortorder[col])
print(sorted_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your ordered list and append them to a new list if they are in your original list.

```
mylist = ["green", "red", "yellow", "blue"]
myorder = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "teal", "blue", "purple"]
final = [color for color in myorder if color in mylist]
#['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']
```